# What could be said about a field extension, if it's Galois Group is fixpointfree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a galois extension, and let the Galoisgroup be fixpoint-free, what could be said about the field extension.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by fixpoint-free?  That $\sigma(x)\ne x\hspace{6pt}\forall x\in L\setminus K, \sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(L,K)$?

Comment: yes (except the identity), i.e. for $\sigma \ne id$ this condition holds.

Comment: Hm, well, $\operatorname{Gal}(L,K)$ has to be simple, for one thing.

Comment: Not only simple but, in fact, it can't have any non-trivial subgroups and, thus, it must be cyclic of prime order.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh yeah, I forgot this was *all* subgroups, not just normal subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Galois correspondence tells us that if $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G=\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$, then the fixed field of $H$ is a proper extension of $K$. Apply this to all the cyclic subgroups of $G$. Prove that $|G|$ must be a prime.